# Como selecionar somente as pessoas com o primeiro nome

Tags: sql, postgresql

Gostaria de saber como fazer para selecionar as pessoas que possuem apenas o primeiro nome, ou seja, não possuem nenhum sobrenome.

Exemplo:

> ```
> Nome
> ----------
> Leonardo Roberto
> Ana
> Júlio
> Maria Ana
> ```

Resultado esperado:

> Ana, Júlio

Comment: Bem vindo ao SOPT. Teria como [edit] seu post e acrescentar o código que esta utilizando, ou o que tentou fazer até o momento? Assim podemos analisar e sugerir uma alteração. Consulte a página [ask] para obter ajuda para o esclarecimento desta pergunta.

Answer (score 2):

Apesar da sua questão estar pouco clara, penso que será simples chegar a uma solução.

Vamos supor que tem a tabela abaixo (exemplo muito básico):

```
CREATE TABLE Pessoas
(
    Nome VARCHAR(255)
)
```

Tabela que contém a seguinte informação:

```
INSERT INTO Pessoas VALUES('Leonardo Roberto')
INSERT INTO Pessoas VALUES('Ana')
INSERT INTO Pessoas VALUES('Júlio')
INSERT INTO Pessoas VALUES('Maria Ana')
```

Para obter os nomes que não tenham sobrenome, basta procurar aqueles que não tenham espaços:

```
SELECT  * 
FROM    Pessoas
WHERE   STRPOS(LTRIM(RTRIM(Nome)), ' ') = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Uma alternativa seria uma chamada à função [`POSITION()`](https://w3resource.com/PostgreSQL/position-function.php); considerando que o nome com sobrenome será sempre separado por um espaço (), pode usar o seguinte:

```
SELECT *
FROM pessoa
WHERE POSITION(' ' in nome) > 0;
```